# ¿Cómo guardar los datos en una estructura?

Tags: c

No sé guardar los datos en una estructura ni pasarlos a binario en un archivo .dat

Además me da un resultado incorrecto con el primer numero de serie debido a que en esa línea cojo el país y tengo un fallo con la cadena.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {

    int *ano;
    char pais;
    float *serie;
    float linea1[10], linea2[10], linea3[10], linea4[10], linea5[10], linea6[10], linea7[10], linea8[10], linea9[10], linea10[10];

}DatosEmpregos;

void Datos_Emprego (FILE *ff) {

    DatosEmpregos Datos;

    if ((ff = fopen("C:\\Users\\pedro\\Desktop\\untitled10\\AUT_jobs_2007_2016.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("\n\nNon foi posible abrir o ficheiro. \n\n");
    } else {

        int a = 10, c = 10;
        char s[100];
        int i, j;
        char *f, *b, z[20];
        char nome[4];

        Datos.ano = (int*)malloc(a*sizeof(int));
        Datos.serie = (float*)malloc(c*sizeof(int));

        if (Datos.ano == NULL) {
            printf("\n\nNo se ha podido reservar el espacio de memoria. ");
        } else if (Datos.serie == NULL) {
            printf("\n\nNo se ha podido reservar el espacio de memoria. ");
        } else {

            fscanf(ff, "%[^,],%[^,]", s, s);
            for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                fscanf(ff, ",\"YR%d\"", &Datos.ano[j]);
            }

            fscanf(ff,"%[^,]", nome);
            fscanf(ff, "%[^,]", s, s);
            for (j=0; j < 10; j++) {
                fscanf(ff, ",\"%f\"", &Datos.linea1[j]);
            }

            fscanf(ff, "%[^,],%[^,]", s, s);
            for (j=0; j < 10; j++) {
                fscanf(ff, ",\"%f\"", &Datos.linea2[j]);
            }

            fscanf(ff, "%[^,],%[^,]", s, s);
            for (j=0; j < 10; j++) {
                fscanf(ff, ",\"%f\"", &Datos.linea3[j]);
            }

            fscanf(ff, "%[^,],%[^,]", s, s);
            for (j=0; j < 10; j++) {
                fscanf(ff, ",\"%f\"", &Datos.linea4[j]);
            }

            fscanf(ff, "%[^,],%[^,]", s, s);
            for (j=0; j < 10; j++) {
                fscanf(ff, ",\"%f\"", &Datos.linea5[j]);
            }

            fscanf(ff, "%[^,],%[^,]", s, s);
            for (j=0; j < 10; j++) {
                fscanf(ff, ",\"%f\"", &Datos.linea6[j]);
            }

            fscanf(ff, "%[^,],%[^,]", s, s);
            for (j=0; j < 10; j++) {
                fscanf(ff, ",\"%f\"", &Datos.linea7[j]);
            }

            fscanf(ff, "%[^,],%[^,]", s, s);
            for (j=0; j < 10; j++) {
                fscanf(ff, ",\"%f\"", &Datos.linea8[j]);
            }

            fscanf(ff, "%[^,],%[^,]", s, s);
            for (j=0; j < 10; j++) {
                fscanf(ff, ",\"%f\"", &Datos.linea9[j]);
            }

            fscanf(ff, "%[^,],%[^,]", s, s);
            for (j=0; j < 10; j++) {
                fscanf(ff, ",\"%f\"", &Datos.linea10[j]);
            }

            printf("\n\nIntroduza a posicion do ano que quere comprobar: \n\n");
            scanf("%i", &j);
            if (j < 1 || j > 10) {
                printf("\n\nLa posicion introducida no es valida. \n\n");
            } else {

                printf("\n\nANO: %i", Datos.ano[j-1]);
                printf("\n\nPAIS: %s", nome);
                printf("\n\n%f", Datos.linea1[j-1]);
                printf("\n\n%f", Datos.linea2[j-1]);
                printf("\n\n%f", Datos.linea3[j-1]);
                printf("\n\n%f", Datos.linea4[j-1]);
                printf("\n\n%f", Datos.linea5[j-1]);
                printf("\n\n%f", Datos.linea6[j-1]);
                printf("\n\n%f", Datos.linea7[j-1]);
                printf("\n\n%f", Datos.linea8[j-1]);
                printf("\n\n%f", Datos.linea9[j-1]);
                printf("\n\n%f\n\n", Datos.linea10[j-1]);

            }
        }

        fclose(ff);

    }



};

int main() {

    FILE *fich;

    if ((fich = fopen("C:\\Users\\pedro\\Desktop\\untitled10\\AUT_jobs_2007_2016.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("\n\nNon foi posible abrir o ficheiro. \n\n");
    }
    else {

        Datos_Emprego (fich);

    }
}
```

Gracias

Comment: Bienvenidx. Ese error al subir la pregunta se da cuando no añades detalles del problema, datos de prueba, salida esperada, salida actual, errores al ejecutar el código, etc. No resumas el error, sé específico. :)

Comment: fscanf(ff,"%[^,],", nome); //se te paso poner una coma

Answer (score -1):

Para guardar una estructura a binario es muy fácil:

```
void gardar_datos(char *nombre_fichero)
{
    FILE *archivo =fopen(nombre_fichero, "wb") ;
    
     fwrite(&Datos,1,sizeof(DatosEmpregos),archivo);
            
    fclose(archivo) ;       
 
}
```